# Uninstall .NET Framework 3.0 SP1 in command line

Tags: .net

I have been trying to uninstall .NET Framework 3.0 SP1 using command line with the `dotnetfx30sp1.exe`.  I have tried the /remove and /uninstall switches but all that happens is it says that it is already installed.  Is there anyone that used the command line uninstall command?  I'm trying to do a silent uninstall but just trying to uninstall first.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using msiexec:

msiexec /x {2BA00471-0328-3743-93BD-FA813353A783} /l*v %temp%\netfx30sp1_uninstall_log.txt /qn

Take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2008/02/19/7805444.aspx).